# Screen Flickering Elementary OS 5.0 Juno

Tags: release-juno, graphic-drivers, graphics, intel

I installed Elementary OS 5.0 Juno a month ago and everything worked smoothly and fine. About a week ago, the screen kept flickering (brightness goes up and down and the screen get distorted every now and then). I have an Intel graphics card which I tried to update (don't know how to remove and and reinstall) and nothing happened. I also opened the BIOS settings page for 15 mins to make sure the screen itself is ok and the problem is with the OS.

Some OS details:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
```